# How to see the value of the cursor in debug mode?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to See the text of the cursor. (the cursor has arguments and its take time to replace the arguments by their value myself) Thus I m trying to use the table v$open_cursor

In the IDE PLSQL developer, I debug a function which calls a cursor.

```
    if not cursorName%isopen then

        --A

        open cBMIS (i_lanId, i_objectName, i_osUser, i_eventType, i_dateFrom, i_dateTo, i_interval);

        --B

    end if;
```

IN A and B I click on execute SQL in debug session in oder to execute this query :

```
select  
         sql_text 
from 
         v$open_cursor
order 
         by last_sql_active_time desc
fetch 
         first 10 rows only
```

In A the cursor hasn’t appear in the result of the query yet.  In B it should have appear, but it doesn’t. Why?

Comment: I assume `A` and `B` are sessions.  I'm not sure what you mean by "In A the cursor hasn't appear in the result of the query yet".  A is the session that you are debugging, right?  Does that mean that the cursor hasn't been opened in A yet?  Or does it mean something else.  Note that when the cursor appears in `v$open_cursor`, it's not going to have the values of the parameters that were used to open the cursor, you're just going to have the text of the SQL statement with bind variables.  It sounds like you are trying to find out the values of the parameters that were used to open the cursor.

Comment: @Justin Cave      A and B are only marks to say when in the debugging i launch the query. In A the cursor has not been opened yet, Therefore it didn't appear. But in B the cursor has been opened